# How to declare a function type throwable?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I know in kotlin-multiplatform, you can annotate a function with @Throws to make it a throwable function. So that converted Java/Swift code has the throws modifier to function signature.

However, when I have a function's parameter who is a function as well, how do I mark this function throwable?

e.g:

```
fun foo(run : () -> Unit) {}
```

the above function has a parameter "run", which takes a closure/function. But this parameter will be compiled without "throws" modifier, so that in Java/Swift, I can't throw anything in the closure that is passed to this function.

I tried to add the @Throws annotation to the function. Putting it outside of function declaration results the foo() function marked as "throws". Putting it in the parameter parenthesis, either before or after the colon, results an error saying annotation is not applicable to target "value parameter"/"type usage"

To summarize, what I'm looking for is something like:

```
fun foo(@Throws(Throwable::class) run : () -> Unit)

or 

fun foo(run : @Throws(Throwable::class) () -> Unit)
```

Any hint/help on this issue is very very appreciated!

Comment: Can you please describe your use case and what do you expect the compiler should do with the `@throws` annotation on the parameter?

Comment: One work around for this would be to create your own interface instead of using Function.  You can then correctly annotate that.  With Kotlin 1.4, lambdas can be used for functional interfaces when called from Kotlin.  Will still have strange wort of needing to return Unit.INSTANCE from Java.

Answer (score 4):

You can not annotate function parameter with @Throws, because the annotation has following targets: AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER and AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR.

Created feature request in Kotlin tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39688